# Best way to override default dropdown-menu css in Twitter Boostrap with Angular JS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a twitter bootstrap web template that I'm integrating with angular ui to develop a SPA. I have been able to do this integration to some level but I want to override the default css that Twitter Boostrap dropdown-men with Angular JS provides. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) Edit the Bootstrap CSS 
You can edit the bootstrap CSS but this means you are assuming all risk for integrating nay future bootstrap changes. I don't recommend it unless you want to trim out all bootstrap CSS except what you need. Only mentioning it because it is an option, though not one I recommend.

Option 2) Create your own CSS to override Bootstrap's CSS
Create a CSS file such as `styles.css` and have it listed after bootstrap's CSS in your HTML file. Then override the styles for what you need. This is pretty easy and allows you to leave Bootstrap untouched.

Option 3) Pay a CSS expert :)

OK, so seriously ... choose option 2.